# What is the correlation between the convex acromion type and rotator cuff tears?

Tags: shoulder, rotator-cuff

What is the correlation between the convex acromion type and rotator cuff tears?

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Acromion&oldid=752100258 only indicates the correlation for the flat, curved and hooked acromion types:

[image]

However, the acromion type may also be convex:

[image]